# lenovo fingerprint not listed in system

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I can't activate fingerprint in my laptop
i expect that fingerprint of lenovo is not installed
also system shows below [image]

my system info is
System  Ubuntu 21.04 Ubuntu 21.04
Arch    x86_64
Kernel  5.11.0-16-generic
Vendor  LENOVO »
Model   IdeaPad Flex 5 14IIL05 81X1 »
Year    2020
HWid    b249c »
Type    convertible
DE  ubuntu:GNOME (Wayland)